# Inconsistency of date format in MS-Excel between formula and cell

Tags: excel

I defined `Custom format`category in `Format cells` as `yyyy/mm/dd` for a column of cells.

When in entering a date in this cells, its shown truly in this cell, but shown as `dd/mm/yyyy` in Formula bar, and when entering in a appropriate application, encountering error in date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date formatting in the Formula bar is not determined by the custom formatting. It is determined by the `Short date` formatting in the `Region` or `Region and Language` settings (depending on OS version)

[image: Region settings]

Comment: I need `YYYY/MM/DD` format, and it's not in the corresponding drop down list. How can I define and use `YYYY/MM/DD` date format?

Comment: My list only contained `dd/MM/yyyy` and `MM/dd/yyyy` format, while I need `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: Go to `Additional Settings...` > `Date`. There you are able to manually specify the format.

Comment: Solved. Thank you.